# Use the Fundamental Theorem to deduce the formula for the area of an ellipse.

Tags: calculus, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Use the Fundamental Theorem (Green's Theorem) to deduce the formula for the area of an ellipse. Hint: find a 1-form whose exterior derivative is $ dxdy $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Green's Theorem states that, for a simply connected region $D$:

$$\oint_{\partial D} (P dx + Q dy) = \iint_D \left ( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right )$$

Choose $P=-y$ and $Q=x$ to get for the area $A(D)$

$$A(D) = \frac{1}{2} \oint_{\partial D} (-y \,dx + x \,dy)$$

For an ellipse, $x=a \cos{t}$, $y=b \sin{t}$, and we get

$$A(D) = \frac{1}{2} a b \int_0^{2 \pi} dt (\cos^2{t} + \sin^2{t}) = \pi \,a\,b$$